# node.js 18.3 native fetch request with a proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, fetch-api

I would like to make a request with a proxy using native fetch node.js 18.3 but i have no idea how.

My code:

```
import proxyAgent from 'proxy-agent';

(async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', {
        agent: new proxyAgent('http://80.48.119.28:8080'),
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data); //it shows my ip
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs `fetch` APIs use [undici](https://github.com/nodejs/undici) which is based on totally different design, [proxy-agent](https://github.com/TooTallNate/proxy-agents) package is not compatible with undici, and can only be used with old API like [http.request](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#httprequestoptions-callback). See issue: https://github.com/TooTallNate/proxy-agents/issues/239 .

Note, undici support proxy, but currently undici's `ProxyAgent` is not exposed to nodejs directly, so you need to install undici package and import it manually. You can track the issue here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43187 .

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the agent in the request Headers

```
import proxyAgent from 'proxy-agent';

(async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', {
      headers: {
        agent: new proxyAgent('http://80.48.119.28:8080'),
      }
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data); //it shows my ip
})();
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. Nodejs fetch use undici which is based on totally different design, "proxy-agent" is not compatible with undici, and can only be used with old API. See issue: https://github.com/TooTallNate/proxy-agents/issues/239